# How to add a button to each row in List View Data Template in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datatemplate

I have this code as my list view:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewPhotoLibrary">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="47"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="X"/>
    <TextBlock Foreground="Teal"/>
   </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and i use a list of string as its item source

```
List<string> libraries = new List<string>(Properties.Settings.Default.Paths.Split(new char[] { ';' }));
            libraries = libraries.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).Distinct().ToList();
            listViewPhotoLibrary.ItemsSource = libraries;
```

My problem is that the list view is not showing the text.
[this is what i get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37F2M.png)

what am I doing wrong and what are some good reads for understanding data templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element in the grid are missing a column number, also the text box has no content, try this:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Content="X"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Teal" Text="Some text"/>
```

To display the actual content of the items in the list, you need to use the `Binding` object, in your case, since the object are just `string` the binding declaration is simple:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Teal" Text="{Binding}"/>
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Teal" Text="{Binding Path=."/>
```

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) is a good start, read [well noted WPF questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf?sort=votes) on SO is also a good idea.